# How to add basic auth header in autobahn client tool

Tags: websocket, autobahn

I want to add basic auth header in the autobahn client tool. How can I achieve that?

#### Current request

```
GET / HTTP/1.1  
User-Agent: AutobahnPython/0.5.2  
Host: 10.35.34.172:9000  
Upgrade: WebSocket  
Connection: Upgrade  
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 1U4OeBs60qkmk1V/8voLOw==  
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 8
```

#### Request I need:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1  
User-Agent: AutobahnPython/0.5.2  
Host: 10.35.34.172:9000  
Authorization: Basic TXlMb2NhdGlvbkFwcDpNeUxvY2F0aW9uQXBwMTIz  
Upgrade: WebSocket  
Connection: Upgrade  
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 1U4OeBs60qkmk1V/8voLOw==  
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 8
```

Note: I don't want autobahn server to authenticate the client.
My scenario is autobahn client --> my server --> autobahn server.
My server will take care of extracting the authorization header and then invoke the autobahn server.

Answer (score 7):

I have implemented options to send custom HTTP headers for both AutobahnPython client and server. You need to use the latest AutobahnPython on GitHub (master branch).

A client can send headers by providing a `headers` keyword argument during construction of the `WebSocketClientFactory` or set headers via `setSessionParameters`.

A server can send headers similar to client, and additionally specify headers when returning from `onConnect`.

**Here is a complete [example](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_httpheaders)**.

Disclaimer: I am original author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.

Comment: Thanks Oberstet. I have updated my code with master branch.  
In your client code http://autobahn.ws/python/tutorials/echo (client.py), I have added header as
factory = WebSocketClientFactory("ws://192.168.2.138:8081", debug = True, headers = {"Authorization: Basic cmljazpyaWNrMTIz"})  

But I am getting error as factory = WebSocketClientFactory("ws://192.168.2.138:8081", debug = True, headers = {"Authorization: Basic cmljazpyaWNrMTIz"})
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please do fetch again the latest code from GitHub, and don't forget to `python setup.py install`. I have also added a complete example: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/websocket/echo_httpheaders

Comment: Do you have an example with autobahn JS client from HTML?

Comment: @RafaelFreitas for autobahn-js you can pass custom headers when initializing a new connection using the `headers` option.  

ex: `new Autobahn.Connection({ headers: { ... }, ...options, });`